# Find unique elements in the lists of lists of objects in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, unique

I have list of objects in Python. Each object contains own list. The list contains some categories of that object. Every list contains exactly 15 elements (could be letter, number or symbol -) eg.

```
['A', 'A', '1', '-', ... , 'B'] or ['-', 'C', 'X', '-', ... , 'D']
```

My goal is to find unique values for each category or more precisely of each position in the list, ideally stored in the form of dictionary, for example something like this:

```
{0: {'A', '-'} 1: {'A', 'C'} ... }
```

So I need to go through of all objects in the list and save those unique values. Is there a way to do this in elegant, pythonic way?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Can you give a few sample inputs and expected outputs?  Also, please indicate what's your original approach and where do you got stuck?

Comment: @DanielHao real inputs are very similar to those in the question (just letters may differ a little). Every list contains exactly 15 elements (could be letter, number or symbol -), every element represent state of one category. So expected output is also very similar, only it may contains more characters. I know how to loop over every object, but I don't know how to loop over lists of objects and store only unique records for every category.

Comment: it's not clear from your example why you got this result:  {0: {'A', '-'}  ... }  'A' is NOT a unique item in the original list: ['A', 'A', '1', '-', ... , 'B']?!

Comment: Yes, sorry, the element does not have to be unique in the list itself. The elements in the list are stored in given order and must be unique only on their position. So on the first position there are unique symbols 'A' and '-'. On the second position there are unique elements 'A' and 'C' etc.. Hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

you can pair objects position wise with each other with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> a=['A', 'A', '1', '-', 'B']
>>> b=['-', 'C', 'X', '-', 'D']
>>> list(zip(a,b))
[('A', '-'), ('A', 'C'), ('1', 'X'), ('-', '-'), ('B', 'D')]
>>>
```

and to get that dictionary from your sample you can add [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to the mix

```
>>> dict(enumerate(zip(a,b)))
{0: ('A', '-'), 1: ('A', 'C'), 2: ('1', 'X'), 3: ('-', '-'), 4: ('B', 'D')}
>>>
```

and to get the unique such pair you can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) to remove duplicates

```
>>> c=['A', 'A', '1', '-', 'B', 'A', 'A', '1', '-', 'B']
>>> d=['-', 'C', 'X', '-', 'D', '-', 'C', 'X', '-', 'D']
>>> list(zip(c,d))
[('A', '-'), ('A', 'C'), ('1', 'X'), ('-', '-'), ('B', 'D'), ('A', '-'), ('A', 'C'), ('1', 'X'), ('-', '-'), ('B', 'D')]
>>> set(zip(c,d))
{('A', '-'), ('1', 'X'), ('A', 'C'), ('-', '-'), ('B', 'D')}
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. Is it possible to use zip on multiple lists or just two?

Comment: you can use `zip` with as many lists as you want